# How to change query_cache_type to 2 in AWS RDS?

Tags: mysql, performance, amazon-rds, query-cache, query-performance

I want to change my AWS RDS parameter `query_cache_type` value to 2 , I have done it in parameter group dashboard as in the given image.
[image]

I have also restarted my mySQL server with the changed parameter,
but when I am checking this by query I am getting a different response:-

[image]

How can I change this static parameter ?

Comment: please refer to this site if you did not create parameter group: https://survivalguides.wordpress.com/2012/07/11/change-the-query-cache-size-amazon-aws-rds/

Comment: @AhmadAbuhasna The parameter group has been created,i just want to change the query_cache_type value, can you suggest me how can this be done?

Comment: Have you also configured the cache sizes? Can you post a screen grab showing all the cache control values - such as size, min_res, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you attached the parameter group to the RDS instance properly? I have just checked on my installation, and things are working as expected. (Note, I do have my cache size set to zero, as for our workload it is not beneficial to enable it)

Parameter Group Settings
[image: Query Cache Settings]

MySQL Query Cache

```
mysql> show global variables like 'query_cache%';
+------------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name                | Value  |
+------------------------------+--------+
| query_cache_limit            | 0      |
| query_cache_min_res_unit     | 512    |
| query_cache_size             | 0      |
| query_cache_type             | DEMAND |
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate | OFF    |
+------------------------------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Parameter Group Assigned to RDS Instance

[image]

Regards,
Dave

Comment: Don't set `query_cache_size` to more than 50M.

Comment: The type should be `OFF` when the size is 0. With `DEMAND` the QC mutex is still used and slows you down - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-configuration.html : `If query_cache_size is 0, you should also set query_cache_type variable to 0. In this case, the server does not acquire the query cache mutex at all, which means that the query cache cannot be enabled at runtime and there is reduced overhead in query execution.`

Comment: @Dave Rix I have successfully implemented DEMAND caching ,and also i am getting cache hits,how do i calculate hit percentage?http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130304/what-is-the-hit-rate-in-case-of-demand-caching

Comment: @jkavalik - totally agree, and in our real workload we do have the query_cache_type set to zero, I just set it to 2 here as an example :)

Comment: @JitinMaherchandani - I wouldn't worry too much about the cache hit ratio - see this blog post from Percona https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/02/28/why-you-should-ignore-mysqls-key-cache-hit-ratio/